# Advantages and disadvantages of starting with list and ending with new array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Why do some people create array lists like this.

`List<T> array = new ArrayList<T>`

and others create array lists like this.

`ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>`

is there a difference? Are there any advantages or disadvantages for favoring one over the other? This question came to me after merging a branch in github and then pulling I noticed that in a Utils class one worker used the second method while others seemed to use the first method.

Comment: list is an interface and the array list is the a class implementing the list... static vs

Answer (score 0):

**list** is an interface and the **array list** is the a class implementing the list...
so basically is a desing way related to **static /dynamic binging**.

[some differences between them](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-dynamic-binding/)

1. Static binding happens **during Compile time** while Dynamic binding occurs during Runtime.
2. private, final and static methods and variables uses static binding and bonded by compiler while virtual methods are bonded during runtime based upon runtime object.
3. Static binding uses Type(Class in Java) information for binding while Dynamic binding uses Object to resolve binding.
4. Overloaded methods are bonded using static binding while overridden methods are bonded using dynamic binding at runtime.